# URL links in Eclipse python code

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I like to document my python code with links to web pages that explain the algorithm in detail.  But I can't make the links 'live', so that just clicking on them in Eclipse brings up the page in the platform browser.

I've just been putting the URL's inside the 3-double-quote pair, then having to manually copy paste them to the browser.

Is there a better way?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451645/python-docstrings-pydev